# How to display only a specific icon from my predefined png image while using font awesome for other fonts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, fonts

So my precise problem stems up from the fact that I am unable to make a vector icon for one of my icons. I have that icon as a image file but if I try to convert it using raster vector image it looks horrible. As I can't make it a vector svg file I can't include that as part of the awesome font.

Now my real problem.
The icon gets displayed using a directive

```
<i class="icon-{variable name}"></i>
```

This variable portion is changed upon the response from my API. For all other icons it will work. However for obvious reasons for the icon I want it won't find it in awesome font. hence when it encounters "icon-custom" I want the css in the awesome font which generally shows something like

```
.icon-wap:before {
    content: "\f102";
}
```

to point and load a specific .png file (my icon).

Is this even possible with the css?
I knew there was a way to using variables.less in bootstrap sprites to load custom glyph. but it seems that's not a possibility now.
So is there a way i can do this?

Comment: It will be great if you can add a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: I was trying to create a jsfiddle.

What I noticed was that the `.icon-*` convention is used in FontAwesome integrated into Bootstrap 2.3.2. Whereas in 2.3.2 it does not use `:before` to render the icon. It rather uses an image sprite.

Bootstrap 3.0.2 uses `.glyphicon.gyphicon-*`.

While FontAwesome when used itself, follows the `.fa.fa-<icon_name>.fa-<icon_size>` convention.

The latter two use `:before` to render icons. So, I am not clear what you are using.

Comment: @MiteshAshar I am actually trying to utilize the FontAwesome by itself (by using some of the icons in it which aren't used). I am building this in a bootstrap environment. That's why that was my last resort that if possible I'll use that to override for that particular icon.

So the css I am referring to is the FontAwesome css which redirects me to the Fonts/icons. I would like to have a way for a specific "icon-something" to load a specific png (icon) instead of the font it generally loads.

If it is still not clear, I'll try to make a jsfiddle out of it!

Comment: Looks doable to me. Only that I need a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to package your icon into a font file just like how font-awesome did. Your icon need to be in vector format.

Font Custom is a tool to convert SVG images into your own font icon set. It requires a couple packages to install from brew or apt-get (Mac and Linux only right now) and then a gem to watch a directory and build the font.